# No option to add Visual C# class in models in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to add C# class in models but there is only option for Visual Basic class. When i click online option, it's showing no items available for Visual C#

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have c# as language installed too. I think you are missing this component

Comment: It seems you are pretty obviously working in a VB.NET project, is that right?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a vb project, you can't add c# classes. One thing you can do is add a new c# library project and then add a reference to it.